# Idiomatic way to handle multiple different async results in Java / Android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I'm writing an android application which at one point handles multiple different asynchronous operations: I have to get the user's location, I receive an identity token from `GoogleAuthUtils` and I do a network request via `OkHttp`. The operations are all started from within the same activity.

Given that they are all different kinds of asynchronous requests, what is the idiomatic way to synchronize them and continue on the UI thread once all three results are available? I am looking for something similar to the way JavaScript handles this with `Promise.all(p1, p2, p3).then(…)`. Is there a way to do this with `AsyncTask`, `Handler`or something similar or do I maybe have to resort to some third party library?

Comment: Have you tried retrofit with rxjava?

Comment: Which android version? In Android N you can use `CompletableFuture`, which is a promise in java 8.

Comment: The Android version should be as low as possible. I know that suggested is API version 14 is suggested, but we're aiming for 9.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi Retrofit doesn't really help because there are multiple libraries involved and it's not just about HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can send your reference of the `Activity` to your `AsyncTask` then notify the activity at the end of the `onPostExecute` function that your task is completed